# rails 4 app with 2 databases: MySQL and Cassandra - where to begin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cassandra, cql, cequel

Hi have an existing rails 4 app which is using a MySQL database.

I now need to add code that creates dynamically a new table for every object and its attributes.

I decided to use a No SQL solution for this. Initially I wanted to use Mongo DB since I was familair with this. However, my company supports only Cassandra/redis/solr. So I have to pick one of these.

I chose Cassandra but Im not finding any tutorials or examples on how to use it with an existing rails app with a MySQL DB.

I found [this](https://github.com/cequel/cequel) ORM for rails-Cassandra but no idea how to make it work with an existing Active record - mysql system.

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Apologize this post has no code. But I couldnt find any answers for this issue on SO so please excuse if any mistakes.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` and `Cequel` will be independent.

As shown in their [docs](https://github.com/cequel/cequel) you extend a model's functionality by including the `Cequel::Record` module.

```
include Cequel::Record
```

In order to use it in rails you (obviously) need to add the proper gem in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'cequel'
```

and create the configuration for the project

```
bundle exec rake cequel:keyspace:create
```

After that, you will have a `config/cequel.yml` from where you will define your settings (as you did in `config/database.yml` for your MySQL)

MySQL models will still use the `ActiveRecord`

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end
```

while `Cassandra` ones will use the `Cequel`

```
class Bar
  include Cequel::Record
  ...
end
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks for clarifying this point. I saw the docs but still needed clarification that this is possible.